# (Drug API with NDC) Drug name with specified strength & NDC Error

Tags: api, openfda, drugs

Our website is a platform for patients to consult with physicians and specialists on-demand.
The doctors will be able to search for the drug name though the database (NDCID drug database integrated in our system i.e open FDA API ). Through this subsection the doctor will be able to verify Allergy details and Active medication; add drug name and strength. The same info will be pushed to e-prescription (third party) platform where doctors will write the prescription for patient and send to pharmacy.

We have implemented Drug API with NDC dictionary to get all drug databases into our system.

**API End point** - https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=finished:true&limit=1

**Problem Statement** –
As per requirement, we need to allow Doctors to add drug strength for the respective drugs. While integrating the open FDA API, we reviewed the available response for the API for locating the drug strength, but were unable to find the same.

We need drug information along with its strength & 11 digit NDC code(packaging NDC). We have illustrated problem statement with following example.

Eg. Consider drug with name **"Lovastatin"**. For this drug we need detail information like below.
Lovastatin tablet (generic)
10 mg
20 mg
40 mg

Lovastatin tablet extended release 24 hr
20 mg
40 mg
60 mg

When we are pulling drug information using NDC API endpoint then we are getting appx. 72 records with brand_name **"Lovastatin"**. This drug information contains values like packaging, active ingredients, brand name, generic name. But not the strength like 10mg, 20mg along with NDCs (packaging code).

Sample API Result from Open FDA  for one of the **"Lovastatin"** drug found (out of 72).

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("601930da98fbb123706a4c94"), 
    "product_ndc" : "70518-0194", 
    "generic_name" : "Lovastatin", 
    "labeler_name" : "REMEDYREPACK INC.", 
    "brand_name" : "Lovastatin", 
    "active_ingredients" : [
        {
            "name" : "LOVASTATIN", 
            "strength" : "10 mg/1"
        }
    ], 
    "finished" : true, 
    "packaging" : [
        {
            "package_ndc" : "70518-0194-0", 
            "description" : "90 TABLET in 1 BOTTLE, PLASTIC (70518-0194-0)", 
            "marketing_start_date" : "20170202", 
            "sample" : false, 
            "ndcid" : "70518019400"
        }, 
        {
            "package_ndc" : "70518-0194-1", 
            "description" : "30 TABLET in 1 BLISTER PACK (70518-0194-1)", 
            "marketing_start_date" : "20171004", 
            "sample" : false, 
            "ndcid" : "70518019401"
        }
    ], 
    "listing_expiration_date" : "20211231", 
    "openfda" : {
        "manufacturer_name" : [
            "REMEDYREPACK INC."
        ], 
        "rxcui" : [
            "197903"
        ], 
        "spl_set_id" : [
            "84a67585-8c8d-4309-b7fa-bd7be330c4a1"
        ], 
        "nui" : [
            "N0000175589", 
            "N0000000121"
        ], 
        "pharm_class_epc" : [
            "HMG-CoA Reductase Inhibitor [EPC]"
        ], 
        "pharm_class_moa" : [
            "Hydroxymethylglutaryl-CoA Reductase Inhibitors [MoA]"
        ], 
        "unii" : [
            "9LHU78OQFD"
        ]
    }, 
    "marketing_category" : "ANDA", 
    "dosage_form" : "TABLET", 
    "spl_id" : "a3d6c1c7-9f51-6937-e053-2a95a90a3d10", 
    "product_type" : "HUMAN PRESCRIPTION DRUG", 
    "route" : [
        "ORAL"
    ], 
    "marketing_start_date" : "20170202", 
    "product_id" : "70518-0194_a3d6c1c7-9f51-6937-e053-2a95a90a3d10", 
    "application_number" : "ANDA075991", 
    "brand_name_base" : "Lovastatin", 
    "pharm_class" : [
        "HMG-CoA Reductase Inhibitor [EPC]", 
        "Hydroxymethylglutaryl-CoA Reductase Inhibitors [MoA]"
    ], 
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2021-03-04T07:38:43.216+0000"), 
    "modifiedOn" : ISODate("2021-03-04T07:38:43.216+0000")
}
```

Third party e-prescription platform integrated on our platform is using 'First data bank' for drug database from where they are getting all the information of drug along with strength & NDCs. Sending the NDC codes or the drugs identified from our platform is not matching for the specified drug strength. As we are not able to locate the desired drug strength on our platform using open FDA API drug db.

For the above example **"Lovastatin 10mg"** they have (Third party e-prescription platform) specific NDCs. They have provided us following NDC against "Lovastatin".
`00185007001,00093092610,00093092606,68180046707,68180046703,68180046701,61442014110,61442014101,68001031400,68180046709,00440669285,00440669281,00440669260,00440669230,00440669201,00440669200,49999029330,52959097430,63629358302`

Out of the shared NDCs (19 records) few of the records are available and matching (10 records) with the open FDA db. Though, the strength for the same is unavailable.

Would be great if you can help us with locating or finding the strength in open API FDA API response for the specified drug.  Also let us know if we are missing something at our end.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to just download the entire NDC database and then run your own queries.

We did that because we didn't want to be contrained by the API.